# Two Language Flask Site With or Without Blueprints

Tags: python, flask

I Just Want to run flask web app for two languages I tried this:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, g

app = Flask(__name__)
bp = Blueprint('frontend', __name__, url_prefix='/<lang_code>')

@bp.url_defaults
def add_language_code(endpoint, values):
    values.setdefault('lang_code', g.lang_code)

@bp.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_lang_code(endpoint, values):
    g.lang_code = values.pop('lang_code')

@bp.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello ' +'!'

@bp.route('/about')
def about():
    return 'Hello ' + '!'

app.register_blueprint(bp, url_defaults={'lang_code': 'en'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My Goal is to have site for two language for English and For Georgian.

I also need to know where to add another Language and how to switch languages in HTML template ?

Comment: Take a look at flask-babel https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/.

Comment: Hello, I need custom translations from database and Babel has such support ?  I also can not write double views for each method, I need app to have prefix languages and methods to be written only once thanks :) that code above woks but base url / says not found (it is not prefixing itself) also I don't know how to switch languages

Comment: No you can not use flask-babel for database translation, because it is static.

Comment: I am using standard way in session language getting translations from database and serving it with context in each method I get language 
lang = get_lanugage()
and rendering template with the lang
but for SEO and other details I need to inject url prefix with language en or ka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, g, redirect, request, \
    session, abort, render_template, url_for, Response, make_response
import datetime



app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates')
main = Blueprint('main', __name__, url_prefix='/<lang_code>')

app.url_map.strict_slashes = False

app.secret_key='p9uyg7yuwriwjigjergkrgrrrr'

app.config['SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES'] = {'ka': 'Georgian', 'en': 'English'}

translation_list = [{ 'name': 'anytrans',
                   'ka': 'ქარ',
                   'en': 'Eng'},
                    { 'name': 'any',
                   'ka': 'რამე',
                   'en': 'Any'},
                    ]


@main.before_request
def ensure_lang_support():
    lang_code = g.get('lang_code', None)
    session['lang_code'] = lang_code
    if lang_code and lang_code not in app.config['SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES'].keys():
        ''' fix for unsupported lang inserted '''
        session['lang_code'] = '/ka/'
        g.lang_code = 'ka'
        return abort(404)

@main.context_processor
def inject_language():
    return dict(sess_lang=g.lang_code)

@main.url_defaults
def add_language_code(endpoint, values):
    if 'lang_code' in values or not g.get('lang_code', None):
        return
    if app.url_map.is_endpoint_expecting(endpoint, 'lang_code'):
        values['lang_code'] = g.lang_code

@main.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_lang_code(endpoint, values):
    g.lang_code = values.pop('lang_code')

@main.route('/change/<new_lang_code>', methods=['POST','GET'])
def change(new_lang_code):
    response = make_response(session["lang_code"])
    session['lang_code'] = new_lang_code
    response.set_cookie('lang_code', new_lang_code)
    return response

@main.after_request
def set_lang_cookie(response):
    response.set_cookie('lang_code', g.lang_code)
    return response

@main.context_processor
def inject_translations():
    return dict(translations=get_translation())


def get_translation():
    lang = g.lang_code
    translations = {}
    for trans in translation_list:
        translations.update({trans['name']:trans[lang]})
    return translations


@main.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@main.route('/home/hale/')
def home():
    url = url_for('main.index')
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/')
def redir():
    lang = request.cookies.get('lang_code',None)
    if lang:
        return redirect('/'+ lang + '/')
    else:
        return redirect('/ka/')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()


{% extends 'html/base.html'  %}

{% block body%}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function change_lang(id){
            $.get('/{{sess_lang}}/change/'+id, function(data){
                var pathname = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
                var newPathname = "";
                for (i = 2; i < pathname.length; i++) {
                    newPathname += "/";
                    newPathname += pathname[i];
                }
                window.location.href = '/'+ id + newPathname
            });
        }

    </script>

{% if sess_lang =='ka' %}
    <p>{{sess_lang}}</p>

    <p onclick='change_lang(id)' id="en" >change</p>

{% else %}
    <p>{{sess_lang}}</p>
     <p onclick='change_lang(id)' id="ka" >change</p>
{% endif %}

<div class="rame">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/{{sess_lang}}/home/hale/">Home</a>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```